# Get an image through jQuery AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, imagesource

The following image tag is in my Login Page

```
<img id="CaptchaImg" alt="Captcha" src="@url.action("Captcha","Login")" style="" />
```

Now when I refresh my login Page, it works fine, and gets the image from the controller, but when I logOut and the login Page renders .the controller method is not being called.Problem is only in IE works fine on Chrome.Is there are work around?
Can I do something with jQuery Ajax call to the controller, I tried this but the success method is not called. Is there any other way?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Login/CaptchaImage',
    datatype: "image",
    success: function(data) {
        debugger
        $('#CaptchaImg').attr('src', data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are u using `img` src like this `"@url.action("Captcha","Login")"` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("Captcha","Login")',
    dataType:"image/jpg",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#CaptchaImg').attr('src', data);
    }
 });
```

Comment: datatype should be `dataType` ?

Comment: url.action should be `Url.Action` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response,Now the control comes to the success function but the format of the data is not proper may be because of wrong data-type.The "Captcha" method returns object of type  "FileContentResult".So would "image/jpeg" be right?

Comment: Please check you are returning image in JPG/GIF, if it is JPG then it will run else change datatype as dataType: "image/gif", Reference- http://msankhala.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/loading-image-through-ajax/

http://forums.asp.net/t/1758165.aspx/1

Comment: Minor bug with this - if you're expecting image/jpg back you need to set `contentType: 'image/jpg'` instead

Answer (score 0):

web Server should return base64 Data. like this

```
{ base64Data:"blahblahblah" }
```

your ajax request content-type could be plain json ;
in your success function in ajax you could do like this

```
    success:function(data){
     var src="data:image/png;base64,"+data.base64Data;
      $('#CaptchaImg').attr(src,src)
}
```