# Asp.met mvc - replace image using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, image

I have a page with an image. I would like to first display a loading gif, and then change the image src using Ajax...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339876/get-a-image-through-jquery-ajax). Here is my code :

```
                    @{
                    if (Model.HavePhoto)
                    {
                        <img id="userPhoto" src="~/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" align="right" class="user-img" />
                        <script>
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("GetPersonPhoto", "Home")',
                                data: { name: "personName" },
                                cache: false,
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "image/png",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#userPhoto').attr('src', data);
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.status);
                                }
                            });
                        </script>
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        <img id="userPhoto" src="~/Content/images/header-default_user.png" align="right" class="user-img" />
                    }
                }
```

My GetPersonPhoto method directly return the image :

```
return File(photo, "image/png");
```

But my Ajax call doesn't works and I get an emtpy error message, and the status is "200"...

It is certainly a wrong way to do it or a problem eith the DataType... How can I do it ?

Comment: why not return image path and set the src property

Comment: Use src directly `<img src="@Url.Action("GetPersonPhoto", "Home" , new { "name" = "personName" })" />`

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to display a gif before loading the image. How can I dot it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onload` event of Image.

Use

```
<img id="userPhoto" src="~/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" align="right" class ="user-img" />
<script>
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '@Url.Action("GetPersonPhoto", "Home" , new { "name" = "personName" })';
    img.onload = function () {
        $('#userPhoto').attr('src', this.src);
    }; 
</script>
```