# Display image immediately after fill textbox

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display an image immediately after fill the textbox, don't need to click any button for get the picture.

I did this in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input value="" id="UserID" name="UserID" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <img id="CaptchaImg" alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("showFoto", "loan")" style="" />
}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("showFoto", "loan")',
        datatype: "image/jpg",
        success: function (UserID) {
            $('#CaptchaImg').attr('src', UserID);
        }
    });
</script>
```

In my controller Loan.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public string showFoto(string UserID)
{
   string ImageID = UserID;
   var virtualPath = string.Format("~/images/profile/{0}.jpg", ImageID);
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(virtualPath)))
   {
      return virtualPath;
   }
   return null;
}
```

My information was from:[get a image through jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339876/get-a-image-through-jquery-ajax)
Please, need your helps... thanks!

Comment: Does your controller method have `[HttpPost]` attribute?

Comment: Why are you doing a POST. It should be a GET.

Comment: And whats the point of `ViewBag.Foto = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(virtualPath)`?

Comment: And the ajax call only runs when you first load the page (at which point the textbox has no value) - you need to handle the `.change()` event of the textbox and assign its value in the ajax call (your not passing any value to `showFoto()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script to handle the `.change` event of the textbox and pass its value to the sever method (note the `change` event occurs when the textbox loses focus)

```
$('#UserID').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("showFoto", "loan")',
    data: { userID: $(this).val() }, // pass the value of the textbox to the method
    datatype: "image/jpg",
    success: function (UserID) {
        $('#CaptchaImg').attr('src', UserID);
    }
  });
});
```